# Display node in multiple context

Tags: 7, theming, blocks, entities

I'm using Drupal 7, and this problem have been tormenting me these past few days :

let's say I'm using the basic content type *Article*, with basic view mode : full and teaser.

[image]

Now I'm creating a new content type *Magazine*, which reference multiple *Article* (with the [module entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference)). On *Magazine* full view mode, I have set that every *Article* will be diplayed in teaser and linked to its content.
[image]

Easy isn't it ? Everything work fine. **Noted that the red block in the sidebar are the same (with [contexte module](https://www.drupal.org/project/context)), and as the title**.

Now I'm creating another new content type *Book*, which also reference multiple *Article*. On *Book* full view mode, *Article* are also displayed as teaser linked to  its content.
And now we have a problem when clicking on a *Article* from book: the sidebar and the title is from *Magazine*, and what I need is to display green block and title from *Book*.

What I get :

[image]

What I want :

[image]

Is there a way to achieve that ? By contrib or Custom ?

P.S. An article can be referenced in Book, or in Magazine, or both, or neither of them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry all, I had completely forgotten about this un-responded question.

It's been a long time so I don't remember the details. After a deep dive in custom and contrib', I managed to get it done with [view_mode_page](https://www.drupal.org/project/view_mode_page) and [context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context)

At first view_mode_page didn't seems to respond to my need, but after more thorough tests, it do the job pretty smoothly.

Comment: In reference to euphoricMV post, it don't work with alias

Answer (score 2):

You can add query string or another argument to the link of article, for example:

```
node/[nid]/magazine or node/[nid]?ct=magazine
node/[nid]/book or node/[nid]?ct=book
```

After that you need to add visibility to the Book and Magazine block that appears in sidebar.

For Book block:

```
node/*/book
```

For Magazine block:

```
node/*/magazine
```

Hope it will help.

P.S. You can add argument or query string to the link of article through **template_preprocess_node** function by changing **$vars['node_url']**.

P.P.S. Just figured out that you can only use new argument, not query string.

Comment: Is this working with alias ?

Comment: Also it seems to solve the problem for the block display. But on Magazine/Book full mode, I will have to alter the link's render the article teaser to "[node_url/node_alias]/[argument]", isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Maybe it would be good to add "node/[nid]/argument" and you can create some automatic url alias on node create or node update. You can do that with rules, of course.

Comment: I didn't manage to get it worked the way you told me, but it help to understand more my need and to find a solution. Thanks you :)